# Proving set statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let

```
A = {x ∈ Z: x = 5a + x for some integer a}
B = {y ∈ Z: y = 10b - 3 for some integer b}
C = {z ∈ Z: z = 10c + 7 for some integer c}
```

Prove or disprove the following statements. 
1. A ⊂ B
2. B ⊂ A
3. B = C

How do we prove a problem like this? For number 1 and 2, do we set the equations equal to each other and try to prove that way?

Comment: The $a,b,c$ mentioned in your question are not "fixed". E.g. can you find for $x\in\mathbb Z$ some integer $a$ such that $x=5a+x$? If the answer is "yes", then you are allowed to conclude that $x\in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $x=5\times0+x$
- $10b-3=10(b-1)+7$

Comment: Why do we make a = 0?

Comment: The first hint tells you that for *every* $x\in\mathbb Z$ there is some integer $a$ with $x=5a+x$. Namely integer $a:=0$. So every element of $\mathbb Z$ appears to be an element of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

To prove that a set $S$ is a subset of another set $T$, we usually consider a generic element $e \in S$ and show that $e \in T$. If we want to disprove the statement that $S \subset T$, we try to find some counterexample that's in $S$ but not $T$.